# Cannot get Xvid video codec to work

Tags: codec, video-codecs

I have several videos that were encoded with XVID MPEG-4 video codec that I cannot get to play correctly on my Windows 7 laptop.  Have no problems playing videos with other codecs.

I have tried downloading the latest version of the codec from XVID and installing it, but that didn't seem to help.

One thing that looks odd to me is that when I go into Media Player and do a Help/About the Xvid codec shows up without a binary file listed. Is this normal?

[image]

Would appreciate any advice or assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using VLC to play that specific file?

Comment: Followed your suggestion, and YES, it will play with VLC. Would still like to fix whatever's wrong so it will play in Media Player and Windows Live Movie Maker. Thanks

Comment: Does VLC play the file without trying to repair it? You could try GSpot or MediaInfo to find out what is the exact codec that the video was done with. Before using VLC I used to install K Lite Codec Pack and almost everything would play....